# Using Autolayout, unable to move the navigation bar down 20px

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a UITabBarController which has four tabs.  One of those tabs opens a my results screen (a UITableViewController).

On showing this screen, I want to move the UINavigationBar down 20px (to make room for a custom UIStatusBar which I show on all screens).

On all my other screens, I add some code to the viewWillAppear method to change the self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y to 20.

but these are all "non-root" screens (i.e. a pushed view with a back button).

However on THIS screen the UINavigationBar must be initially visible, even though it is the root view.  I use the same code, but it doesn't move the view down.

I'm assuming autolayout is moving it back into position, so I tried adding this code into viewWillLayoutSubviews and viewDidLayoutSubviews.  But when I do this the navigationbar doesn't move down until the first time the tableview is scrolled.

What do I need to do to force the navigationBar to move down (and stay down) before the screen appears?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using storyboards? Set the Y in storyboards to 20, Make your viewcontroller implement UINavigation bar, then add this code:

```
-(UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar{
        return UIBarPositionTopAttached;

}
```

This will tell the app that the navigation bar is to be attached, it will remain at 20px but extend the background all the way up.. So essentially it'll look like it's at y = 20.